# In .Net Core, how can I set a variable in a controller from HttpContext to use in all of the controller methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I would like to set a variable that can be accessed by other methods within the controller.

```
public class ReportsController : Controller
{

    public readonly int loggedInUserID = int.Parse(HttpContext.User.Claims.First(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        /*I would like to be able to access this variable in many controller methods
        without having to copy 'int.Parse(HttpContext.User.Claims.First(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value)'
        for each reference.*/

        int userID = loggedInUserID;

        return View();
    }
}
```

When I try to create the loggedInUserID variable, the error message states: `A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'ControllerBase.HttpContext.`  Is there a different way to create a variable that I can reference within the controller?

Comment: You don't. What are you trying to do? If you want the current user, check the HttpContext directly. If there is no user it means there is no user - perhaps the call was anonymous so the user was never authenticated

Comment: have you tried making it a property with `=>` instead? that's only evaluated once you _access_ it, not when you create it (and drop the readonly)

Comment: Move you variable loggedInUserID within the methods to be able to access the HttpContext. It's not available at load time so you'll have to look it up when a method is called

Comment: @FranzGleichmann That was the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to achieve can be done if you define a `get` for the field:

```
public int _loggedInUserID { get => int.Parse(HttpContext.User.Claims.First(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value); }
```

Then your code should compile.